# How to sum hidden input field values with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a form list that includes hidden fields with money values that I would like a sum of when the page loads.

My input fields are the following
`<input type="hidden" name="jcartItemPrice[]" value="4.99">`
`<input type="hidden" name="jcartItemPrice[]" value="6.00">`
`<input type="hidden" name="jcartItemPrice[]" value="2.50">`

How can I use jquery to get the total sum of those values. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply loop through the items and collect the summand values:

```
sum = 0;
$('[name^=jcartItemPrice]').each(function() {
    sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: quotes around the type selector value are mandatory as per the jQuery documentation

Answer (score 1):

You could just loop through them with jQuery, and add the values together

```
var total;
$("input[type=hidden]").each(function() {
    total += $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: quotes around the type selector value are mandatory as per the jQuery documentation

Comment: Wow. I did not know that. I've been using those types of selectors for years, and it has worked like a charm all this time... Any idea why they are? They're not in the CSS spec, though..

Comment: honestly, not a clue.  It may be a simple convention with no ramifications, but I'm just doing what the docs tell me to do: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: Well, I can see why they would matter when you include one or more whitespaces in your query, but not for _all_ queries. I'm just gonna stick it to the man (Resig), and keep not-quoting it until it breaks.

Answer (score 1):

```
var total = 0;
$('input[type="hidden"]').each(function() {
    total += parseFloat(this.value);
});
```